# Category Promotion Rule

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, promotions

I have magento 1.9.2.3. I want to apply the discount to whole category.

Actually, I have 2 categories and both have same products, but I want to apply the discount to one category.

I go to **`Promotions -> Catalogue Pricing Rule`** and **`Apply the Rule`** to one category, but discount is showing on both categories, although both categories have different id's.

Is it possible to apply the discount to one category?

Comment: As you said you have same Products in both categories, discount is applied for all the products present in one category & its reflecting everywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have same Products in both categories, discount is applied for all the products present in one category & its reflecting everywhere on the site.

In the **worst case** , If you want to achieve this, worst idea is the **create duplicate products with different skus** and you can assign Promotion rule to one category id & it will works. but i dont prefer this solution.